# Reuse `ui-route` controller that expects a `resolve`d parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router

I want to be able to reuse my `ui-router`-wired controllers. They currently receive parameters from `ui-router` `resolve` to render their templates. Can I reuse those controllers without `ui-router`?

For example, I do this with `ui-router`:

```
.controller('DetailController', function ($scope, detailData) {
    $scope.controllerDetail = detailData + "is awesome!";
})
.config(function ($stateprovider) {
    $stateprovider.state('detailState', {
        resolve: {
            detailData: function () { return "John Doe"; }
        },
        template: '<p>{{ controllerDetail }}</p>',
        controller: 'DetailController'
    }
}
```

Now, I want to use the same controller to render a fixed sub-panel elsewhere. For example:

```
<master ng-init='childData="Jane Smith"'>
    <detail ng-controller='DetailController' ng-controller-params="{ detailData : childData">
        <p>{{ controllerDetail }}</p>
    </detail>
</master>
```

Of course, in practice, there are actually template files, and some functionality in the controller worth de-duplicating. Also, the `resolve` data in the first example and `init` data in the second example both arrive over the wire, but in the second example it arrives as a child object of a larger request rather than an individually-navigated item. Also, I assign my controllers in directives rather via HTML attributes.

Comment: What is `ng-controller-params` ?

Comment: I made it up. It's the imaginary solution to my question. I want to pass a named argument to my controller, as it expects because of the way `resolve` works.

Comment: oh ok.. Got it, pls ignore my stupid question. What cant you just resolve it via another state registration (), after all it is a better practice IMHO to instantiate controllers via router rather than instantiating it via ng-controller directive as much as possible.

Comment: no not at all, I often fail to get my question across here. regarding another state registration, there is no navigating to that element in this case. it is one of a few other micro-panels that display under main panel.

Comment: You do not necessarily need navigation actually, you could create child states with ui.router unlike ngRouter, something like a partial view to isolate a piece of functionality for example.

Comment: @PSL I'm currently using child states, but can multiple child states be active simultaneously? I mean, the master panel itself is a child state. It contains multiple micro-panels.

Comment: I believe so, provided its parent state is active.

Comment: I'm confused, but I'm investigating.

Comment: So far, I've found [multiple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313492/angular-ui-router-get-two-states-active-in-parallel) [sources](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/339) that say parallel active states are not supported. You may be thinking of multiple named views, which do support a controller, but I don't see anything in the docs about passing them parameters. That doesn't mean it's not supported, since the docs are still a work-in-progress...

Comment: It looks like named views will work for me (provided all of my panels can be manageably contained within a state that will always be parent to them. Views [can indeed use](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-ui-router.html) `resolve`s and `resolve` blocks are [automatically injected](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies) with the results of parent `resolve`s. These two features will work in my case. If you would like to answer the question feel free, otherwise I will with my completed code tomorrow.

Comment: I once provided an answer to a related (perhaps not exact duplicate) question - see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28870149/968155. Named views, as @PSL suggested, is definitely one approach and perhaps ideal, but this is here for completeness-sake.

Comment: @New Dev Do you know if you can inject a non-static object in that way? for example `ng-inject="{ foo: myScopeObject.childForRendering }"` If so, that's exactly the approach I was hoping for when I asked the question, although PSL's suggestion is working quite nicely for me so far.

Comment: @shannon, yes - see the example in plunker in that question. In one instance `name` variable is passed

Comment: Ok, took me a second, I was doing something silly. Yes, that's exactly what I was initially looking for. Not sure what the meta says in this case. At a minimum if you post the link to the related question and your directive, I'll upvote it, although I should probably accept PSL's approach if I'm to treat it as a different question.

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate of another question, delete. But I think there is value in having @PSL's answer here. And I don't think there is any value in me posting a link to another answer (or duplicating the answer, for that matter) as an answer here - a link in a comment should suffice.

Comment: I think we are meant to scan the answers, ordered by upvotes, for potential solutions to a question that matches our needs. I don't know the meta well enough to say what is right here, but my feel is that even though it is a different question - exemplified by the fact that the solution I'm using (PSL's) would not solve the other related question - your solution is still a valuable, real answer to mine. If my question has value to anyone else, that is. :D

Answer (score 1):

In my case, which is a similar though limited subcase, I had multiple `ui-router` routes with `resolve()` defined, and ***only one place*** with the controller instantiated in a template via `ng-controller`, and the value passed to the controller in such case was a known, constant value.

In such case, you can simply do

```
.value('detailData', 'here goes the default/fallback value')
```

If you have multiple usages of `ng-controller` which should have different `detailData`, you need to find a better solution obviously.